# How to get list of notifications were send to specified user onesignal api?

Tags: onesignal

I used onesignal to send notifications for user. Now I want to get list of notifications were send to specified user via onesignal api but I don't see document for that. 
This is api link but it's not related with user:
https://documentation.onesignal.com/reference#view-notifications

Can you help me, thank you so much!